# gRPC property order not matching proto?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm starting out on gRPC, my proto looks like:

```
message Customer {
    int64 customerId = 1;
    string firstName = 2;
    string lastName = 3;
    repeated string roles = 4; 
}
```

but BloomRPC is displaying as:

```
{
  "roles": [
    "User",
    "Admin"
  ],
  "customerId": "100000",
  "firstName": "Bob",
  "lastName": "Jenkins"
}
```

Shouldn't roles be last?

Comment: I might just be ignorant here, but why does ordering matter? I imagine the JSON is from having already processed proto "off the wire," and the ordering is a side-effect of the dictionary / map implementation. (I may very well be wrong.)

Comment: @AndrewCheong Only matters for human readability / debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the fields has no effect on how the messages are serialized. Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#assigning_field_numbers) and [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#order) for more information.